# Clickable links (from hyperref package) do not work upon selecting a subset of pages via "printing to file" in evince

Tags: latex, hyperlink, evince, pdflatex

I use the hyperref package for clickable cross-referencing within my document. It works well, however, if I want to send a colleague just a part of the document by using the "print to file" feature in evince to create a pdf file only with the relevant pages, the clickability breaks down. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230614/clickable-links-from-hyperref-package-do-not-work-upon-selecting-a-subset-of-p/230681#230681) (where it might not belong to) and it sais that you can use the `pdftk` tool to split the file, which works well (does not break the links).